# no-repeat center center vs cover

Tags: html, css

What the difference between `background: no-repeat center center;`
and `background-size: cover;` ?

Both achieve basically the same effect as a background image on my website. No difference as far as I can tell in results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`background: no-repeat centre centre;`
is saying place a background image in the element, but only show one instance of it (`no-repeat`), try looking at the[`background-repeat`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) property to see other options.

The CSS then says place the image in the vertical `centre`, and horizontal `centre` of the element. This is related to the [`background-position`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property.

It might be worth you trying to reducing the image size to something small 10px x 10px to see the effect of no-repeat, vs repeat-x, repeat-y and repeat.

[`background-size:`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) declares how big you want the background image to be (this allows dynamic resizing of the image much like height and width in the html img tag), this is a property introduced in CSS3.

By default this is the background-image's default/native resolution. By using the be cover value you are saying scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

I have put links on each of the properties so you can see the possible values for each. I recommend you look at all of the background-* attributes on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp). Look on the left hand side and they are all listed ;)

Alternatively if you're new to CSS, I would recommend this free course by [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-html-and-css--ud304) which has plenty of video tutorials and guides you through HTML & CSS web development.

Comment: Thanks Jon :) The problem is mainly with the wording. How exactly does it maintain it as large as possible? visually/functionally I don't see much difference between the two.

Comment: lets say you have a background image which is 10x10 (width x height). In an element which is 100 x 120.
css:
x{
width:100px;
height:120px;
background:url('somebgimage.jpg') no-repeat centre centre;
background-size:auto; /* auto is the default value if this is not explicitly set. */
}
<div id="x"></div>

Comment: This says get one instance of somebgimage.jpg and place it in the centre of div's with an id of x. So it gets the native width of somebgimage.jpg (lets say 10px) and then gets the width of the matching element (div with id of x, so 100px), it then says place the left hand side of some image ((100-(10/2))/2) pixels from the left hand side of the element, and it does this for the height too. ((120-(10/2)) but this time from the top of the element.

See the effect of background repeat here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-repeat&preval=repeat-x

Comment: what happens when you have the css:
x{
width:100px;
height:120px;
background:url('somebgimage.jpg');
background-size:cover;
}

This says for each x, place an image in the most top left hand corner of the element. Then figure out the width and height of the container element. We want to know what the biggest of these two is. This is the height (120px). Now if the image smaller than the container height or width, stretch the image, so that the smallest measure(width or height) is the same size as the maximum width or height of the container.

Comment: This is what the cover bit does. Now because we haven't included the background no-repeat, by default it is set to repeat. 

To see the background-size options in action and probably make more sense see this demo:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Comment: Wow awesome answer you really made me understand. Thank you again.